# Varnish 4.0 - Drupal says it is working successfully but it isn't in my headers

Tags: proxies, caching

I have a very basic Varnish setup:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

And that's about it.

I have the Varnish module installed as well with the standard defaults and flush cache on cron.

However when I try to find X-Varnish: HIT, I find absolutely nothing in my header.

Here's my header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date:   Wed, 08 Nov 2017 23:22:00 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Drupal-Cache: HIT
Content-Language:   en
X-Frame-Options:    SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible:    IE=edge
X-Generator:    Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Link:   <http://ifollosports.com/>; rel="canonical",<http://ifollosports.com/>; rel="shortlink"
Cache-Control:  public, max-age=86400
Expires:    Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Vary:   Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding:   gzip
Set-Cookie: bb2_screener_=1510183320+147.75.99.51; path=/
Etag:   "1510183079-1"
Last-Modified:  Wed, 08 Nov 2017 23:17:59 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
```

What would be causing Varnish to not work? Is there some other configuration setting that Drupal needs? I want to be very clear - the module is reporting that Varnish IS working.

I am going based off this link:

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/install-varnish-on-drupal-7/

Answer (score 1):

`Set-Cookie: bb2_screener_=1510183320+147.75.99.51; path=/`

Varnish will not save a page to the cache if there is a `Set-Cookie` header on the response.

Comment: Hrm, is there anyway to use both Bad Behavior as well as Varnish at the same time?